# How to implement a protocol that have associatedtype by using another protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

There I have two Protocol:

1.

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
    associatedtype T: Identifiable<String>
    
    var array: [T]
}
```

2. 

```
protocol AnotherProtocol: Identifiable<String> {
   var id: String
}
```

Then I try to do this, but not woking, said "does not conform to protocol"

```
struct MyStruct: BaseProtocol {
   //no working
   var array: [any AnotherProtocol]
   //or:
   typealias T = any AnotherProtocol // Same, not working

}
```

Is that impossible to do that?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/5133585). Basically the compiler is afraid that you might declare static requirements in `AnotherProtocol`.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks! I think that's the reason that not allow me to do that.  Anyway, I already use different way to avoid this situation.